# Twitter API friendships/create not working

Tags: php, twitter

I'm having a problem with the Twitter API. I'm trying to follow a specific user but the API always return the following error:

```
{"errors":[{"code":108,"message":"Cannot find specified user."}]}
```

I've tried passing user_id, screen_name and both, but I always get the same result, although I'm pretty sure I'm actually passing the right values.

This is the code I'm using:

```
    $options = array( 
        CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $header,
        CURLOPT_HEADER => false,
        CURLOPT_URL => $this->url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 10,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST => false,
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postfields,
        CURLOPT_POST => true
    );
    $feed = curl_init();
    curl_setopt_array($feed, $options);
    $json = curl_exec($feed);
    curl_close($feed);
```

where $postfields is an associative array containing either user_id with the id of the user to follow of screen_naam with the screen name. I get both values from the Twitter API, so they should be correct. I've tried other users as well, bt the result is the same.

Both the APP consumer id/key as the oauth token/secret as read/write and working (if I change them, I get an authentication error).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Worked this one out quite a while ago, just forgot about this question here. Turned out to be some small problem with the curl request, not with the Twitter API. From the heart, I believe it was the presence of CURLOPT_POST in the options array. Removing that did still do a POST (probably because CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS was still present), but did make the call work as expected.

Answer (score 0):

To whom you want to follow the user has blocked or is not allowing to follow him. In that case it gives the error "Cannot find specified user" in Twitter (api).